# macOS Sierra : What kind of RAID can i create with 4 USB 3.0 hard drives

Tags: macos, raid

I'm on macOS Sierra and I have 4 external LaCie Porsche 5TB P'9230 USB 3.0.

What is the best RAID I can create.

My first option is RAID 1+0 so i have a total of 10TB of data on stripping the first 2 drive and this 10TB is mirroring on the 2 last drive.

So do I have a better RAID solution. I try to read on RAID on wikipedia so it's talk about other kind of RAID with mathematic formula and i have difficulties to see how can i setup this with macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

As per your title:

> What kind of RAID can I create with 4 USB 3.0 hard drives

RAID 0 (stripe across the drives),
RAID 1 (mirror, which you can do with 4 copies of the data for insane safety)
RAID 5 (¾ of data storage, but a write GAP, not recommended).
RAID 10 (stripe and mirror).

Or if you partition the drive into partitions you could add many more combinations. RAID 50, 60, multiple arrays, ... so many choices.

> I try to read on RAID on wikipedia so it's talk about other kind of RAID
>   with mathematic formula and i have difficulties to see how can i setup
>   this with macOS Sierra.

This post on our sistersite [sf] explain RAID nice a easy: https://serverfault.com/questions/339128/what-are-the-different-widely-used-raid-levels-and-when-should-i-consider-them

It also highlights an important question with the `and when should I consider using them`. What is your goal? Just to play around with all kinds of RAID levels, seeing how it performs? Figuring out how your USB3 bus is shared?  Or do you have a specific goal: E.g. Backup in case a single HDD fails? More read speed? Or more speed at any cost, ignoring redundancies?

What is your goal?

Comment: My goal is i have the maximum disk space and a backup if one drive fail. It's to write my huge iTune library (2.5To just for iTunes Library) and many other important files. This is why i think RAID 10 is the best for me. So i need to have others "eyes" to explore if i have other possibilities. My internal SSD is already backuped by the "new" TimeCapsule 3GO with Time Machine.

Comment: RAID5 best fits that, with two notes: 1) Write gap (see the link in my post for explanation of that). 2) RAID is not backup, it lightning hits you still loose all.